If $|A| \le |B| \le |C|$ and $A \subseteq C$ does there exist $D$ with $A \subseteq D \subseteq C$ and $|B| = |D|$?
Suppose that $|A| \le |B| \le |C|$ and $A \subseteq C$. Assuming ZF axioms, but not AC, does there necessarily exist a set $D$ such that $A \subseteq D \subseteq C$ and $|B| = |D|$?
Here is my proof which assumes AC (but only for case 3):
Case 1: $C$ is finite.
Let $x,y,z$ be finite ordinals such that $|x| = |A| , |y| = |B| , |z| = |C|$. Let $E = C-A$.
We have $|y-x| \le |z-x| = |E|$ since $y \le z$. So I can choose a subset $F$ of $E$ with cardinality $y-x$. Then I can set $D = A \cup F$. I have $A \subseteq A \cup F \subseteq A \cup E = C$ and $|D| = |A \cup F| = |A| + |F| = x+y-x = y = |B|$ since $A$ and $F$ are disjoint.
Case 2: $C$ is infinite and $|A| = |C|$.
Then let $D = A$. I have $A = D$ so $A \subseteq D$ and $A \subseteq C$ so $D \subseteq C$. By the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem, $|A| \le |B| \le |C|=|A|$ so $|A| = |B|$. Therefore, $|D| = |B|$.
Case 3: $C$ is infinite and $|A| \lt |C|$.
Let $E = C-A$. If AC is true then $|E| = |C|$. Since $|A| \le |B|$, there exists a set $F$ such that $|A| + |F| = |B|$ so $|F| \le |B| \le |C| = |E|$. Let $G$ be a subset of $E$ such that $|F| = |G|$. Let $D = A \cup G$. I have $A \subseteq A \cup G \subseteq A \cup E = C$ and $|D| = |A \cup G| = |A| + |G| = |A| + |F| = |B|$ since $A$ and $G$ are disjoint.
However, in case 3, I assumed AC to prove the result. My question is:
Is this possible to prove without AC? Or is this possibly false in ZF without AC?

It surely can't be false (at least if ZF is consistent).

@Matsmir "possibly false", meaning that its negation is consistent (that is, there is a model of ZF where the statement is false).

@prem spaces inside mathJax do not changes anything.

Oh , I know that. No worries , @Lucenaposition , I wanted to correct "Schorder" to "Schroeder" , though MSE requires that we must change a minimum number of characters. I usually use Spaces inside MathJAX to ensure that some brackets are not missing. Lastly , I made those three cases "Obviously" mutually exclusive.

@prem if you have 2k reputation or change the title, you don't need to change 6 characters in the body.

Oh , I did not know that. That is nice to know. I have already given the +1 , so I can not make the change from 1990 to 2000 for you here.

If my memory serves me right, this is one of those nightmarish proofs that I always hated with a lot of nitpicky combinatorics in them. But the answer (again, memory pending), is a nutshell, is that yes, this is possible.

I wonder if the two answers here would be suitable for a (short) paper. After all, this is at least as interesting as the proof of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem. And btw I would have expected that the result cannot be proven without AC ...

@MartinBrandenburg: I am fairly sure that this already appears in the literature. I'm just buried under tons of work and couldn't go and fish out the reference. But the two answers were exactly the kind of thing that I remembered, and these aren't the kind of proofs that I would come up with on my own, so I doubt that it was my fairly limited ability to do these kind of magic tricks.

I want to provide a visualisation of why Giorgio's proof works, which I think makes it much more intuitive.
Fixing injections $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$, we can think of the set $A \cup g(B)$ as a partial dynamical system under the function $gf$, and we can partition it into trajectories. Anything in $A$ has an image under $gf$, and anything in $g(B) \setminus A$ is at the end of its trajectory, while anything in $A \setminus g(B)$ is at the start of its trajectory. This means we end up with exactly $8$ types of trajectory:

The cycle trajectory ($5$) includes fixed points. The finite length trajectory ($1$) includes going straight from $A \setminus g(B)$ to $g(B) \setminus A$. I accidentally omitted trajectories $7$ and $8$, which are the same as $1$ and $2$ but starting in $A \cap g(B)$.
We want an injection $\phi: g(B) \to A \cup g(B)$ which moves points in $g(B)$ so that the image contains $A$. Then the image of $g(B)$ under that injection will be our $D$. Trajectories $3$ to $8$ can be left alone, because they don't contain any points in $A$ that aren't already in $g(B)$. The two types of trajectory that are a problem are types $1$ and $2$, because the start of each trajectory is in $A$ but not $g(B)$, so we need to move points to fill these spaces in.
We can do this just by moving every point in these trajectories that is in $g(B)$ back one step- i.e. setting $\phi(x) = (gf)^{-1}(x)$ for any $x$ in trajectories of type $1$ or $2$. And we can let $\phi$ be the identity everywhere else. The set that you end up with as $D$ after moving elements like this is the whole of $A \cup g(B)$ except for the final elements of trajectories of type $1$.
My $\phi$ is $h^{-1}$ from Giorgio's proof, and Giorgio's proof moved the final element in trajectories of type $1$ to the first position and left the other elements alone, rather than shifting them all by one, but other than that, this is the same proof.
I prefer this version because $\phi$ can be defined more simply as $(gf)^{-1}(x)$ if $x$'s trajectory starts in $A \setminus B$ and $\phi(x) = x$ otherwise.

I believe the solution is to use a Cantor Bernstein like trick. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$ be injections and let $\Gamma_0=A\setminus g(B)$. Define inductively $\Gamma_{i+1}=\Gamma_i\cap (g\circ f)^{-i-1}(A)$ and $\Gamma_\omega=\bigcap_{i\in\omega} \Gamma_i$. By definition we have that for all $i \in \omega$ $(g\circ f)^i(\Gamma_\omega)\subseteq A $.
Let $i\in j\in \omega$, we have that $\Gamma_i\subseteq \Gamma_0$ and $(g\circ f)^{j-i}(\Gamma_j)\subseteq g(B)$ so $\Gamma_i\cap (g\circ f)^{j-i}(\Gamma_j)=\emptyset$ since $\Gamma_0\cap g(B)=\emptyset$ by definition. So $(g\circ f)^{i+1}(\Gamma_i)\cap(g\circ f)^{j+1}(\Gamma_j)=\emptyset$ since $(g\circ f)^{i+1}$ is an injection.
So $\Gamma_0$ is partitioned by $\{B_i=\Gamma_i\setminus \Gamma_{i+1}:i\in\omega\}\cup\{\Gamma_\omega\}$. By construction we have that $(g\circ f)^{i+1}(B_i)$, are pairwise disjoint and disjoint from $A$. Set $D=A\cup g(B)\setminus \bigcup_{i\in\omega} (g\circ f)^{i+1}(B_i)$. We need to show that $D$ is in bijection with $g(B)$. Let $h:D\rightarrow g(B)$ be the function which is the identity on $g(B)\setminus \bigcup_{i\in \omega}(g\circ f)^i (\Gamma_\omega)$, is equal to $(g\circ f)^i$ on $B_i$ and equal to $(g\circ f)$ on $\bigcup_{i\in \omega}(g\circ f)^i (\Gamma_\omega)$. It should be straight forward to verifty that $h$ is a bijection.

If $\gamma \in \Gamma_0$ isn't in $g(B)$ then it has no preimage under $gf$, so $\Gamma_1$ is empty.

@ZoeAllen But $(g\circ f)(\gamma)$ can be in $A$ and in such case $\gamma\in \Gamma_0\cap (g\circ f)^{-1}(A)$.
